# How does Java reserve/use memory?

Tags: java, macos, jvm

This is probably a noob question, but I need to run a java application processing a large dataset. So I went about -Xmx14G, knowing that my machine has 16G of physical memory.

A short while later, boom, I am being notified by my operating system that my startup disk is almost full. I checked my process, there's no OOM exception, just that it stalled. Checked my activity monitor, doesn't says the application runs at full memory capacity.

How does the JVM reserves/use memory?

Comment: How much memory is everything else using?

Comment: When you use storage on most modern OSes, the system allocates "swap space" on disk for the storage, so that it can "page" that storage out and "page in" another process when necessary.  Exactly how this is done depends on the OS -- I think Windows allocates a single swap area, but Linux likely allocates a space per process.

Comment: It sounds like OS X is eagerly ensuring the memory capacity/backing in swap. OTOH, Linux is fairly willing to [overcommit](http://www.etalabs.net/overcommit.html): "Overcommit refers to the practice of giving out virtual memory with no guarantee that physical storage for it exists" (but Linux is not OS X, of course and I cannot find anywhere to suggest that OS X allows overcomitting as such).

Comment: Not sure if you are developing this application with some IDE and debugging it a lot. Then it wouldn't hurt to clean the project after a while. Just guessing tho.

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8037920/tomcat-memory-consumption-is-more-than-heap-permgen-space (it uses much more than just heap, don't give it a max heap close to your actual free ram size)

Comment: Ok 1 thing I observed is, when I use xmx the amount of inactive memory jumps up by about that much. Later, I see my swap file jumps up, but my inactive memory still has about 7gb left. Why is the os not utilizing the inactive memory but insteads swap out to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the JVM allocates new memory until the heap is full, in which case it garbage collects, freeing up non-referenced objects. If you allocated 14GB for the heap, chances are it will consume that much memory.

Answer (score 0):

There is another JVM argument `-Xms<size>` it' initial heap size. If we do not set it explicitly JVM will choose one automatically depending on PC configuration. This value is never that big, typically 64M. Later JVM may allocate more memory up to max. But it happens only when the app really uses it. If actual memory usage decreases JVM will shrink the memory to a smaller size.